# How do I set the id of an apex:pageBlockTable row?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I'd like to be able to assign each row in a table an Id so I can easily find the row(s) later using JavaScript. I see where I can set the id of the table but I'd like to also assign an id to each row with a unique value that will make the row I want easy to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  <apex:page standardController="Account">
     <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>

 <table>
    <apex:repeat value="{!Account.contacts}" var="item">
      <tr id="hello{!rowNum}"><td>{!item.Name}</td></tr>
     <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
   </apex:repeat>
  </table>
</apex:page>
```

Another solution using apex variable

[image]

Comment: I know I could do it this way. I was hoping I didn't have to rewrite the page that someone else had written. Sadly, it looks like a rewrite is in order.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use HTML5 you can take advantage of the custom attributes prefixed with 'data-'. I use this in tables where I want to grab rows and know the SF Id for javascript remoting.

See the sample below from a table I use and then perform actions on the rows using JS remoting

```
<apex:outputPanel id="topAccounts">         
    <div  id="topAccounts" class="myTable">                 
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Reason</td>
                <td>Executive Sponsor</td>
            </tr>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!noAccounts}">
            <tr>
                <td>No Accounts Listed</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
            </tr>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:repeat value="{!topAccounts}" var="a">
                <tr data-SFid="{!a.Id}">
                    <td><div class="removeButton account" style="float:left;position:absolute;"><apex:image style="width:16px; height:16px;" url="{!URLFOR($Resource.VF_Images, 'delete-32.png')}"/></div>{!a.Name}</td>
                    <td><div class="output account">{!a.Territory_Plan_Top_Account_Reason__c}</div><div class="inlineEdit"><apex:inputField value="{!a.Territory_Plan_Top_Account_Reason__c}"/></div></td>
                    <td><div class="output account">{!a.Territory_Plan_Top_Account_Executive__c}</div><div class="inlineEdit"><apex:inputField value="{!a.Territory_Plan_Top_Account_Executive__c}"/></div></td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>                    
    </div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

The important snippet being the  inside the repeat tag

```
<apex:repeat value="{!topAccounts}" var="a">
    <tr data-SFid="{!a.Id}">
```

This is assigning the SF id to a custom attribute of the .  This will allow us to get the element using javascript later on, and to know the SF id of the object within the

> EDIT

Effectively each row in the table has a unique identifier, and as a bonus it carries the SF Id of the object being presented in that row.

I have some jQuery on a button that resides in each row, that goes and gets the Salesforce ID for that row and passes it into a function that has my JS remoting call in it

```
j$('.removeButton.account').click(function(){
     console.log(j$(this).closest('tr').attr('data-SFid'));
     removeAccount(j$(this).closest('tr').attr('data-SFid'));
});
```

If you just want to get the <tr> element in JavaScript, then do:

```
var tr = $("tr").find("[data-SFid='" + id + "']");
```

Comment: Answer would be awesome if you showed the snippet of jQuery to retrieve a row based on its ID...

Comment: My case is a bit different.  I don't grab a row based on the ID, I actually have a button each row 'RemoveButton' and I have jQuery that retrieves the data-SFid of the closest <tr>

Comment: Love the use of the new HTML5 custom attributes. I have to remember that I'm not forced to hack-around the Visualforce id mangling to use jQuery.

Comment: No worries, @Dunc44 - I just added the magic line of code :-)

Comment: @meta, looks like we were updating it at the same time

Comment: No problem - I added my line back :-)

Comment: One problem with using the data-xxxx attribute is that IE does not support it and unfortunately, our company has declared IE to be the default browser for the company.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign an id to a row in a repeat tag, the id value is a concatenated string of the thePageId:theRepeatId:theRowId. There's quite a good blog post about how this works, with references to the Salesforce documentation:

http://watro.tumblr.com/post/9615587212/getting-ids-with-jquery-on-apex-tags

Comment: Sorry greenstork. I know how to GET the id. What I need to do is SET the ID of the <tr> tags under the <table> tag created when you use the pageBlockTable apex tag in a VisualForce page.

Comment: The example I posted uses jQuery to select the id. Are you asking how to use jQuery to get by an id and then set it to something?

Comment: If you're repeating over a collection of objects, what would you want the id to be? What defines its uniqueness?

Comment: What the id is, isn't all that important. What I want to do is set the id of the <tr> element but I do not see a way to do that. I know I could change and use the <apex:repeat> tag and do my own <tr> tags but I was hoping to not rewrite a whole page that has been in service for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

As @GreenStork mentioned there is a deterministic way to identify the id of row in a page block table, but you're not able to directly set the ids of the rows.

If you're having trouble finding a particular row based on a different attribute then the row number you might consider inserting a bonus element into one of the page block table columns with an id you define that can then be traversed up to the parent `<tr>`.

Another option would be to take a look at the `rowclasses` attribute of the pageblock table which allows you to supply a comma-separated list of CSS classes that get applied in a repeating order and which can be used to find a particular row.

Beyond that we'd need to know more about your use case and why @GreenStork's approach isn't easy enough for you to provide better suggestions.

Comment: The problem with using rowClass is that it must be a static value. It cannot contain variables so that I can set the id or some other attribute to a value based on data in the row. What I'd like to do is something like in a table of users, have the <tr id="{!usr.Id}"> kind of thing.

Comment: In that case you'll want to either build the table manually using apex:repeat as @mohith is suggesting, alternatively as I suggested just output a dummy span or something with the user id as the id, search for that and traverse up, unfortunately if you're looking to directly set the ids of the `<tr>`s with a page block table you've hit a wall

Comment: I've been trying to hack things with javascript but it looks like a full page rewrite with the apex:repeat tag will be required. I was hoping I didn't have to but I guess there's no choice. At least it all pays the same. :(

Comment: Bummer, I've been able to get by in the past with something like this.  One of the columns has the record id then just traverse up to the tr, i.e. `j$("[id='hiddenspan#" + userId + "']").parents("tr")`.  Best of luck (do upvote if this answer has been helpful)

Comment: The problem is setting the id of the tr tag. You can't set the id for a rendered tr tag from the apex:pageBlockTable iterator. That is the whole problem. If I could do that, I'd be done and on to the next item to work on.

Comment: On the same page there, just seems like setting the id of a child of that tr tag will get you the same result quickly, easy to find and manipulate in javascript.  Like I said, that's worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I resolved my problem by rewriting the page. There isn't a way I can control the ID of a  tag from the apex:pageBlockTable tag so I built the table with standard  and  tags. I then used the apex:repeat tag for the iteration through the records. I thought this would be my only option but I was hoping there would be a way to not to have to rewrite the page. Now that I can set the id of the record, it is very easy to find the record using javascript.

Thanks for the suggestions though. This is still a learning process.